# Charge accumulated on a hemispherical bulge on a conducting sphere

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Consider a conducting sphere of radius $R$ which has a small hemispherical bulge on the surface of radius $r$. The sphere is given a charge $Q$.

[image]

The expression for the charge accumulated on the hemispherical bulge is approximately given by:
$\frac{Qr^2}{2R^2}$ (Charge on the bulge accumulates in a negligibly small region as far as possible from the centre of the sphere. Therefore, this charge can satisfactorily be treated as a point charge)

I found this written in a book and would like to know how this expression was derived.

### Edit

This is the same expression we get if we assume uniform charge density over the entire surface, but I would like a more rigorous explaination why this should be the case

Comment: Isn't that just what you get if you assume uniform charge density over the entire surface?  (In the limit $r \ll R$, of course.)

Comment: Yes but how is that a valid assumption? The charge accumulated on the hemisphere will affect the charge distribution of the remaining sphere right? Even if $r << R$

Comment: I suppose one could make an hand-waving argument that the charge on the "bump" is still approximately the same distance from most other points on the sphere as it would be in the absence of the "bump", which implies that the charge density over most of the surface would be unaffected by the bump's presence.  But a more rigorous argument would be better and I don't immediately see one.

Comment: The sentence "Charge on the bulge accumulates in a negligibly small region as far as possible from the center of the sphere." seems wrong to me. It doesn't seem like that would make the bulge an equipotential. I believe conductors always have continuous surface charge distributions. Also the book may just be asserting something "back of the envelope"